# Sliding Panel - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm experimenting with a 'panel' that is suppose to slide when clicked although I'm having trouble understanding as to why the 'panel' does not slide when clicked. Can anyone enlightened me on this topic? I'm also open to any other suggestions about my code in general.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slide Panel</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Now you see me!</p>
    </div>
    <p class="slide"><div class="pull-me">Slide Up/Down</div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS (edited, fixed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pull-me').click(function() {
    $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
})
```

Correct Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3kt10v3b/

<del>JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kt10v3b/</del>

Comment: I think you've just flip-flopped a ) and a }.  Switch the order of the )}; after `$('.panel').slideToggle('slow');` to });

Comment: Wow...that did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this, here is the correct code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slide Panel</title>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel">
            <br/><br/>
            <p>Now you see me!</p>
        </div>

        <p class="slide"><div class="pull-me">Slide Up/Down</div></p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pull-me').click(function() {
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
})
```

Solution on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kt10v3b/)

Thanks to @Jonathan Michalik's comment